# My Javascript animations aren't working properly. Receiving TypeError: r is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, developer-tools, webflow

I'm converting a website from Webflow to Wordpress and for some reason, I can't get my scripts to execute my animations properly. When looking at the developer's console I just get an error of `TypeError: r is undefined`.

The animation I'm expecting to happen involves the Navigation. It's supposed to go from a transparent background with white nav links to a white nav background with black nav links. This happens from scrolling up or down the page.

Check out the Wordpress site here: https://ghimortgagetemp.com/

Check out the working version in Webflow: http://wtylerconsulting-ghi-mortgage.webflow.io/

Ignore the CSS differences, just trying to get the header animations to work.

Comment: check again that you have well referenced your `r` variable

Comment: This was designed and developed in Webflow, so I am not familiar with how the javascript and jquery really works here to be able to figure all of that out

Answer (score 0):

seems script tag not included properly. Please fix the script tag issue.

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: Still getting the same issue here. Not sure what to do next

Comment: check you `modernizer` css and `Normalize` css. css not included properly. check image 2